# Special graphs with efficient minimum clique cover solutions

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, np-complete

I would like to obtain a list of special graphs where there exist *polynomial* algorithms to find the minimum (vertex) clique cover. Some of the known cases are:

- Perfect graph including bipartite graphs, chordal graphs, complete graphs
- Triangle-free graph

Does there exist any types of graphs other than the ones listed above, such that there exist polynomial algorithms for their minimum clique cover problem?

Comment: What ae your thoughts?

Comment: I think it is polynomial time solvable on graphs of bounded treewidth.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Perfect graph is very general. It contains too many special cases. This makes me wonder whether there exists any special case that is not perfect graph, or triangle-free graph.

Comment: @ManuelLafond Tree can be viewed as a special case of bipartite graphs. Hence, it still belongs to the category of perfect graph. I would like to find cases whose minimum vertex clique cover an be solved efficiently, but they do not belong to perfect graph or triangle-free graphs.

Comment: @firefighter Bounded treewidth is not the same as tree.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth